# Primefaces 6: configure faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, faces-config

I must set explicit navigation in my web application (Java 8 + Primefaces 6).
I don't know these technologies very well but I would like to set for every xhtml page a general name to view in the url.

So I created a page test.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="formId">
<p:inputText...
<p:commandButton id="btn" 
value="test"
action="#{myBeanViewScoped.test()}" />
</h:form>
```

The method test return an xhtml page if there are not errors.
If I add as suffix in the return statement the code:

```
return "/calledPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
```

works correctly.
I read some articles about this and I tried to remove the suffix "?faces-redirect=true" and to add in my faces-config.xml this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>             
    </application>

    <navigation-rule>
         <display-name>test</display-name>
         <from-view-id>/test.html</from-view-id>
         <description>test</description>
         <navigation-case>
             <display-name>authenticated</display-name>
             <description>authenticated</description>
             <from-action>#{myBeanViewScoped.test}</from-action>
             <from-outcome>/calledPage.xhtml</from-outcome>
             <to-view-id>/calledPage.xhtml</to-view-id>
             <redirect />
         </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

The application does not generate errors, but I see in the URL always test.xhtml and not "authenticated".
Where is my fault?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing? Sob...

Comment: You don't need path in `from-outcome`. It can be regular string `<from-outcome>calledPage</from-outcome>`. And your method can return this string: `return "calledPage";`.

Comment: the redirect does not work

Comment: It means you have it wrong. Remove unneeded part from `navigation-rule`. Do it like ` <navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
   <redirect />
  </navigation-case> </navigation-rule>`